# how to loop through a $.post callback?

Tags: jquery

how to loop through a `$.post` callback function?

Here's the code I would like to loop through....

```
$.post("p.php",{config: config1, test: test1}, function(data)
{

});
```

Comment: What exact response does the server return to this AJAX request that you would like to loop through? Is it a JSON object or something?

Comment: What do you mean by "loop through"? I don't see any loops in your code.

Comment: the response from the server are four p-tags <p></p> and need to place them inside a predefined list (<li></li>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.each` method to loop through an array or objects. Following are the examples with array and object looping using `$.each` method.

Looping an array

```
$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) { 
    alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

Looping an object

```
var map = { 
  'flammable': 'inflammable', 
  'duh': 'no duh' 
}; 
$.each(map, function(key, value) { 
    alert(key + ': ' + value); 
});
```

As you mentioned in the comments the `response` contains 4 `p` tags and you need to append them to an `li` tag on the page, you can try this.

```
$.post("p.php",
    { config: config1, test: test1}, 
    function(data){ 
      //if you have an to li then use id selector or 
      //if you have a class to li then use class selector
      $('liSelector').append(data);
});
```

Comment: how does your answer relate to callback function of $.post?

Comment: In `post` callback you will get `data` which is either an array or object as per your question. Using `data` object you can loop through it as described in my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to loop through each echo statement return from the service call

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(k,v) {

...

});
```

Comment: your solution is giving indiviual characters to the key, value

Comment: Your response must not be an array or an object. What is the exact format of the response?